# ST_Union() vs ST_Node(ST_Collect()) on many intersecting ST_ExteriorRing(circle)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, computational-geometry

I have almost 10,000 circles of the same size which I'm using to create a heatmap based on the number of overlapping circles.

[image]

I have two versions of step 2 running. Is one more efficient than the other? Is there a different approach that I should try?

Here's how I'm trying to accomplish this:

1. get the outlines of the circles (ran very fast)

   > ```
   > create table circle_outlines as 
   >     SELECT distinct ST_ExteriorRing(the_circle) AS the_geom FROM circle_list;
   >     create index idx_geom_circle_outlines  on circle_outlines  using gist (the_geom);
   >     select distinct geometrytype(the_geom) from circle_outlines ; -- LINESTRING
   > ```
   >
   > The output of this table in QGIS:
   >   At a scale of 1:38,167,029 - [oi60.tinypic.com/23uwytv.jpg][2]
   >   ooming into the northeast dense area at a scale of 1:234,378 - [oi59.tinypic.com/96i4xt.jpg][2]
2. combine the lines (**see end of post for 2 approaches being considered**)
3. a. check out the geom type created, if interested (should be GEOMETRYCOLLECTION)

   b. polygonize from the merged borders (ST_Dump((ST_Polygonize(the_geom)))
4. add points inside using ST_PointOnSurface(polygonized_geoms)
5. calculate num_overlaps

**The two step 2s that I'm trying are**:

```
create table noded_circles as 
SELECT ST_Node(ST_Collect(the_geom)) AS the_geom FROM circle_outlines;
-- been running 7 hours - 100% cpu - 2199 MB (24%) memory
```

And:

```
create table noded_circles as 
SELECT ST_Union(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM circle_outlines;
-- been running 43 hours - 100% cpu - 4086 MB (48%) memory
```

So for "flattening" line strings of intersecting circles of the same size, is there a difference in performance between st_union() and st_node(st_collect())? Is there a better way?

--update: both queries were killed due to insufficient memory.

Comment: Could you possibly just add a couple of lines as to what the final output should look like.  It looks like an interesting problem, but there are a lot of steps.

Comment: I create tables for most steps. Step 1 results in 10K rows: Linestrings. Step 2 should result in 1 row: MultiLineString. Step 3b should result in N rows: multilinestring, where N is the number of enclosed areas by any circle borders. Step 4 should result in N Points (stored in same table as 3b). Using the initial circle list, populate table 3b with count of trues for st_contains(initial_circle,point_inside). This end result will have the polygon, point_inside, and number of circles that overlap that point. The random point_inside should represent the whole area of the polygon.

Comment: Also, if it helps. I just checked the results from Step 1, every circle has 33 points (using ST_numpoints(the_geom) )

Comment: Think I'll have to go through this with a set of small random circles, to wrap my head around what is going on. Have either of your queries finished yet, btw?

Comment: I SigTerm'd the st_union() query because the other query caught up to the memory used in half the time. So, the ST_node(ST_collect()) is still running - 80 hours chugging along at 100% of a cpu, 59% memory used (virt: 4979M) - if there are any other stats from htop, please let me know.

Comment: I would say something has gone wrong, 10,000 33 point circles should not take this long. I haven't got round to doing any testing yet. Sorry.

Comment: Decided to throw the circle rings into QGIS. Heres a screenshot http://oi60.tinypic.com/23uwytv.jpg Could it be an issue with areas where two points might be tangent to each other?

Comment: The USA in circles :D. I don't know, in my experience, Postgres (well actually GEOS), can sometimes crash with strange intersection errors. Thanks for picture, it helps to get an idea of your problem.

Comment: So the scale of the previous image was 1:38,167,029. Zooming into that dense area at a scale of 1:234,378 I get this visual http://oi59.tinypic.com/96i4xt.jpg

Comment: The computational complexity starts to get clearer. You might want to edit the question with those images?

Comment: I have come up with another possible approach for the query. Apologies if I have misunderstood your requirements. It is hard to come up with any exact numbers, as the run time is so sensitive to the radius of the circles, the size of the grid, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to create a random set of 10,000 points on a 10,000 by 10,000 grid with point radius of 500.

```
drop table circles; 
create table circles as select g as id, 
    st_buffer(st_makepoint(random()*10000, random()*10000), 500) as geom 
from generate_series(1, 10000) g; 
create index ix_spatial_circles on circles using gist(geom);
```

Using that, I came up with the following query which generates a list of original polygon IDs, the number of other polygons that intersect this, the intersection and the area. For the above grid of 10,000 circles with a 500 radius on a 10,000 grid, this query ran in around 20 minutes on one of our servers. I'm not sure it is worth going into hardware specifics, as I suspect the complexity of the calculation is very dependent on the density of the grid, the radius of the circles, etc, so setting up an environment exactly the same as yours is problematic.

```
select id, max(total_intersected) as "total intersected", st_area(st_union(geom)) as area   
from 
  (select a.id as id, array_agg(b.id) as b_int, 
          sum(case when st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)='t' then 1 else 0 end) as total_intersected, 
          array_agg(b.geom) as geom 
  from 
    circles a, circles b 
  where  st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)  group by a.id) agg 
where id=any(b_int) group by id, geom order by max(total_intersected) desc;
```

The main idea in the subquery is to find all of the polygons (by ID) that intersect every other polygon (using a spatial self-join) and to build an array of these IDs (`array_agg(b.id)`, as finding whether two polygons intersect, is faster than finding their actual intersection; and then, in the outer query, find the actual intersections, but only considering those polygons that are known to intersect for each input polygon, ie, the `where id=any(b_int)` part. I suspect that this might be faster than attempting to union all the circles (polygons) in one go using ST_Collect or ST_Union, as you are operating on polygons known to intersect, rather than all the polygons in one giant intersection.

For what it is worth, I did some testing on random set of points comparing ST_Union(geom) and ST_Node(ST_Collect(geom)) and on the whole ST_Union was fractionally faster, but I think there are too many free variables for this to be a very scientific finding.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to check out this approach when I have access to my system after the holiday. Until then, I am trying to understand the query and result. Which part will return the intersection polygons - arrayagg? Being new to postgis, I'm not sure what to expect from an arrayagg(geometry). From what i think i read, this might return whether a whole circle intersects and does not accout for part of it? I may be wrong, Will do some testing either tomorrow or Tuesday.

Comment: In other words, would the simplest case of two circles return the the intersection as "2"? And the non intersecting portions as " 1"?

Comment: Array_agg does nothing other that aggregrate them together in an array, matching the array formed by the IDs that intersect each polygon in the sub-query, so that they can be passed to ST_Union in the outer query.

Comment: So I ran this on a 100 circle sample and couldn't figure out how to get results for the portions of the polygons. So using this image as something to follow: http://s2.postimg.org/pun30mh0p/circlesoverlap.jpg Would I be able to derive this from your query's results? From my testing, I think I would get "4" for the black circle since 4 overlaps them. However, most of black as far as my use is concerned would be "1" since a lot of it isn't overlapping anything. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to use your query though - any insight would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by results for the portions of the polygons. Do you mean to get the geometry of the intersected bits?

Comment: Right - so the geometry st_intersection(red,black) should have a value of 2, but the geometry (red - st_intersection(red,black)) should have a value of 1. Or rather it doesn't have to be an integer, it can be any unit value where an extra intersecting circle adds a multiplier to that. So geometry that is St_intersection(black,blue,yellow) is 3x the geometry (red - st_intersection(red,black))

Comment: Unfortunately, the image link is down, but I think what you need is to use st_intersection(geom) where I have put st_area(st_union(geom)) to get the actual intersected geometry and max(total_intersected) gives you the total number of intersected polygons. If you could put the picture back up, I will revisit.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I ended up going with was the HeatMap plugin in QGIS. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html 
I used a Uniform kernel to allow me to categorize the # of overlaps by value of the raster.